# Optimal join from a column to the concatenation of those columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, query-optimization

I have a table `TableLHS` with a column `ObjInfo`:

```
ObjInfo
_________
X/132642/A1
X/432753/34
Y/437483/2B
```

which I would like to join to `TableRHS`, with columns:

```
ObjType        ObjNum           ObjFlag
_______        _________        _______
X              00132642         A1
X              00432753         34
Y              00437483         2B
```

So the join here involves 1) dropping the leading zeroes from `ObjNumber`, and 2) concatenating the three columns in `TableRHS` together.

My best shot at the join is:

```
SELECT ... FROM TableLHS
JOIN TableRHS ON 
        TableLHS.ObjInfo = TableRHS.ObjType + '/' +
        SUBSTRING ( TableRHS.ObjNum, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', TableRHS.ObjNum+'.'), LEN( TableRHS.ObjNum ) ) + 
        '/' + TableRHS.ObjFlag
```

My current performance could use some improvement. Is there a smarter way of tackling this?

e.g. Is there a more effective way of getting past the leading zeroes in `ObjNum`? Would it be faster to work the other way round, and try to split `ObjInfo` on the slashes? Would performing this operation on every row nullify the effect of an index on `ObjNum`?

Comment: Learn the basics of relational & SQL optimization/implementation/performance by query engines in general via textbooks & the web & SO & in particular via DBMS manual--all immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. Appropriate research is expected for questions. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get around the "integers" with leading zeroes would be to do a formal cast to the integer type, then cast back to varchar to use in building the path expression for the join.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableLHS t1
INNER JOIN TableRHS t2
    ON t1.ObjInfo = t2.ObjType + '/' + CAST(CAST(t2.ObjNum AS INT) AS VARCHAR(12)) +
                    '/' + t2.ObjFlag;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo